# Max10 LVCMOS input setup and hold timing

Tags: fpga, timing, timing-analysis

I am struggling to find the minimum setup and hold timings for single-ended 3.3V LVCMOS inputs in the datasheet. I'm especially puzzled that the [datasheet](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/m10_datasheet.pdf) and [handbook](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/m10_handbook.pdf) differentiate between low-speed and high-speed pins without stating the actual difference between the two.

I really would like to have some ballpark numbers prior to coding.

Comment: c'mon, show some respect, link to the specific data sheet you're referring to

Comment: I presume you are talking about P34 of that document. If so did you read the paragraph above the table where it points you to information about the difference between the two.

Comment: "For more information about the high-speed and low-speed I/O performance pins, refer to the respective device pin-out files.", followed by a link to all the pin-out files for each device.

Comment: The device pin-out files detail which pin belongs to which group but do not go into detail on what the differences are

Comment: The table on p.34 seems to refer to differential signalling, however I'm looking for single-ended 3.3V LVCMOS.

Comment: I am guessing that the max10 does not have input register right at the input pin. So the register would be in an internal cell, therefore it is not possible to define the setup and hold time until after "place and route" where the data line and clock distribution propagation can be estimated. Perhaps it would have been nice if Altera would publish a typical or a best case, but I suppose that could have misled some people.